# R - How to compare two words sentence if order is not same?

Tags: r, string-comparison

Lets take example

```
z <- "Dikesh Faldu"
y <- "Faldu Dikesh"
```

I want to get process both of this variable and give me same output as "DikeshFaldu"

lets put another example

i have one variable that has all this values like

```
[1] dikesh faldu
[2] xyz abc
[3] faldu dikesh
[4] anything like
[5] but only
[6] two words
[7] only but
```

.........

then i want output like

```
[1] dikeshfaldu
[2] xyzabc
[3] dikeshfaldu
[4] anythinglike
[5] butonly
[6] twowords
[7] butonly
```

or

```
[1] faldudikesh
[2] xyzabc
[3] faldudikesh
[4] anythinglike
[5] onlybut
[6] twowords
[7] onlybut
```

Comment: stringsplit, then sort then paste them back together. This is valid if order doesn't matter: NameSurname or SurnameName

Comment: That comment is really the answer. You should probably post it as such!

Comment: @RonakShah - `strsplit` is vectorized.  No need for the inner loop. `lapply(strsplit(c(z, y), " "), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=""))`.  Could prob do `Reduce(identical, ...)` on that to finish 'er off.

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer How can I pass a list in there? `strsplit` doesnt accept lists.

Comment: Use a character vector, not a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the inputs by @zx8754 , @Dirty Sock Sniffer and @RHertel, you can try,

```
sapply(strsplit(charvec, " "), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=""))

#[1] "dikeshfaldu"  "abcxyz"       "dikeshfaldu"  "anythinglike" "butonly"     
#[6] "twowords"     "butonly"
```

where

```
charvec <- c("dikesh faldu", "xyz abc", "faldu dikesh", "anything like", 
              "but only", "two words", "only but")
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first case, match one or more spaces (`\\s+`) and replace it with `""` in `sub`

```
sub("\\s+", "", z)
#[1] "DikeshFaldu"
```

and for second case, capture the non-white space as a group and rearrange the backreference.

```
sub("(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)", "\\2\\1", y)
#[1] "DikeshFaldu"
```

---

If the `sort` is based on alphabetic ordering, then we use `stri_extract` from `stringi` to extract the words, `sort` it and `paste` together

```
library(stringi)
vapply(stri_extract_all(c(z,y), regex = "\\w+"), function(x)
            paste(sort(x), collapse=""), character(1))
#[1] "DikeshFaldu" "DikeshFaldu"
```

Using the updated vector in OP's post

```
vapply(stri_extract_all(charvec, regex = "\\w+"), 
       function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=""), character(1))
#[1] "dikeshfaldu"  "abcxyz"       "dikeshfaldu"  "anythinglike" 
#[5] "butonly"      "twowords"     "butonly"
```

#### data

```
charvec <- c("dikesh faldu", "xyz abc", "faldu dikesh", "anything like", 
           "but only", "two words", "only but")
```

Comment: Stating the obvious, but then you'll need to now in advance with which scenario you're dealing. My experience with old data is that you don't because it's so inconsistent :-(

Comment: @Jasper The OP didn't mention which way it needs to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the R code that you're looking for. Same as what [zx8754](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680068/zx8754) mentioned.

```
z <- "Dikesh Faldu"
y <- "Faldu Dikesh"

sort(unlist(strsplit(z,split=' '))) == sort(unlist(strsplit(y,split=' ')))

[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: You forgot to paste the the split strings back together. That's why there are two "TRUE" outputs. Maybe use this instead: `reorderedNames <- function(x) paste(sort(unlist(strsplit(x, split=' '))), collapse = '');
identical(reorderedNames(z), reorderedNames(y))`

Comment: I think yours deserves to be a marked answer :) Why don't you add it?

Comment: @DikeshFaldu Using the function described in my first comment, you could try: `theNames <- c("dikesh faldu", "xyz abc", "faldu dikesh", "anything like", "but only", "two words", "only but"); unname(sapply(theNames, reorderedNames))`.